# Raising a function above zero without changing its integrals

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Question 1:

Let $f$ be a bounded function from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with the following properties:

1. For every $x\in[0,1]$, $f(x)\geq 0$.
2. For every Borel subset $B\subseteq [0,1]$ with positive length, $\int_{x\in B}{f(x)dx}>0$.

Is it possible to define a function $g$ from $[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$ with the following properties:

1. For every $x\in[0,1]$, $g(x)> 0$.
2. For every Borel subset $B\subseteq [0,1]$, $\int_{x\in B}{g(x)dx}=\int_{x\in B}{f(x)dx}$
   ?

---

Question 2 (is it equivalent to Question 1?):

Let $F$ be a non-negative, non-atomic measure on the Borel subsets of $[0,1]$. For every Borel subset $B$ with positive length: $F(B)>0$. Is it possible to define a measure $G$ such that:

1. The derivative of $G$ is strictly positive in $[0,1]$;
2. For every Borel subset $B\subseteq [0,1]$, $F(B)=G(B)$
   ?

EDIT: by "derivative" of a measure I mean the [Radon-Nikodym derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem), i.e, a function $f$ such that for every Borel subset $B$: $\int_{x\in B}{f(x) dx} = F(B)$ and similarly for $g, G$.

I now read that the Radon-Nikodym derivative is uniquely defined up to a null set (a set of length 0). So, my question 2 boils down to the following:

** Given a measure which is strictly positive on all Borel subsets of $[0,1]$, does it always have a Radon-Nikodym derivative which is strictly positive in $[0,1]$? **

Comment: First quesion: Define $g=1$ on $f^{-1}(\{0\}), g= f$ elsewhere.

Comment: Q 2: What do you mean by the derivative of $F?$

Comment: Doesn't the second condition on your measure simply mean $F=G $ (also, your choice of names for measures is slightly awkward)?  So that would mean that you simply want to know if $F $ satisfies the first condition.

Comment: @zhw I mean the Radon–Nikodym derivative.

Comment: @PhoemueX I think so but I am not sure, so I wanted to make it clear.